# When I use PyCharm and odoo, [Errno 2] No such file or directory Process finished with exit code 2

Tags: python, docker, odoo, pycharm, odoo-8

I install odoo on the local docker container.
And I want to use Pycharm edit or run  my python file in the container's, I mount local `custom_addons` directory into container, and run file `sf` on the PyCharm, but encounter below error message :

> 91626f8b18b:python -u /opt/project/custom_addons/sf.py
>   python: can't open file '/opt/project/custom_addons/sf.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>
> Process finished with exit code 2

Here is my screenshot:

[image]

And following is my python interpreter on the PyCharm settings' screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your path, sir. Right click the file, "sf.py", and copy the path via the "Copy Path" option within the context menu.

Comment: Yeah, I have try this but it doesn't work at all. Do we have another alternative choices?

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running PyCharm on? As

"This container mounts your project directory into the container at /opt/project in the container. Note: On Linux, you currently have to perform this volume mapping manually."

https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/12/using-docker-in-pycharm/

(this may have changed in the mean time)

Comment: OS:Ubuntu 16.04. I'll try this again.